# Is there a way to automate the creation of a file needed by a container in VS Code Remote-Containers before it runs?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, containers, vscode-devcontainer

This relates specifically to Remote-Containers with VS Code using a docker-compose file to define the services. One of those services in this case is MariaDB which takes an environment variable to specify the location of a file which contains the password for the DB user. The file must exist when the container starts or it will throw an error which could be difficult for a novice to diagnose. There is a default value which the file can contain but if I commit it to the public repository developers can no longer change it locally without the risk of the change being committed. When a developer builds a local environment from the repository, it's okay to use the default value and they shouldn't be required to create files in special locations before opening the container.

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference), inside `devcontainer.json` there is a property called `initializeCommand` which seems like it would be the place to run some code to copy a default file to the right location, but the developer could be running VS Code in Mac or on Windows. Is there a cross-platform way of making sure the environment is prepared before it gets launched? I want this automated so developers don't have to remember or know to do this before getting started.

Basically, it should automatically test if `secrets/sql-password.txt` exists and copy `secrets/sql-default-password.txt` there only if the file is missing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I should be possible to use the initializeCommand in the .devcontainer/devcontainer.json to do something like this

Here is an example of a cross-platform way of calling out with a makefile. You would just need to create the scripts to then create the other files on a per platform basis:

Install make on both platforms and make sure it's available in the CI system

```
# for windows use chocolatey
choco install -y make

# if you want powershell-core
choco install -y powershell-core
```

and use that to choose the correct calls to make:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT) 
    detected_OS := Windows
else
    detected_OS := $(shell sh -c 'uname 2>/dev/null || echo Unknown')
endif

ifeq ($(detected_OS),Windows)
    INITIALIZERS=initialize-windows
else ifeq ($(detected_OS),Darwin)
    INITIALIZERS=initialize-macos
else
    INITIALIZERS=initialize-linux
endif

ifneq (, $(shell which pwsh))
    SHELL_COMMAND=pwsh
else ifneq (, $(shell which powershell))
    SHELL_COMMAND=powershell
endif

initialize: $(INITIALIZERS)

initialize-windows:
    @echo "Initializing Windows..."
    $(SHELL_COMMAND) -File .devcontainer/setup-ssh-agent.ps1

initialize-macos:
    @echo "Initializing Linux..."

initialize-linux:
    @echo "Initializing Linux..."
```

call from .devcontainer/devcontainer.json with:

```json
"initializeCommand": "make initialize --ignore-errors -f .devcontainer/Makefile",
```