# How to create a cross-platform initializeCommand for Visual Studio Code's Dev Container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, cross-platform, development-environment, vscode-devcontainer

Let's assume that I have:

- `.env` file which is `.gitignore`d
- `.env.dev.dist` etc. kind of files to copy to `.env` for each environment and fill in some more secret variables that are blank by default
- `devcontainer.json` that is supposed to be as automated as possible, so I'd like at the very least to copy `.env.dev.dist` file to `.env` if it doesn't exist yet and open the copied `.env` in VSCode

I saw there's `initializeCommand` option for `devcontainer.json` that could help with that as it runs on the host before containers are initialized. However, I don't see how I could possibly create a script that would work on all systems, as syntax for mentioned task(s) differs between them.

Any option I'm missing to define separate commands per system?

Also, reference to a similar unanswered question that has a bit different main question: [Is there a way to automate the creation of a file needed by a container in VS Code Remote-Containers before it runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372540/is-there-a-way-to-automate-the-creation-of-a-file-needed-by-a-container-in-vs-co)

Comment: I added an issue for this in case anyone is interested in following; https://github.com/devcontainers/spec/issues/347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install make on both platforms

```
# for windows use chocolatey
choco install -y make

# if you want powershell-core
choco install -y powershell-core
```

and use that to choose the correct calls to make:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  INITIALIZERS=initialize-windows
else
  INITIALIZERS=initialize-linux
endif

ifneq (, $(shell which pwsh))
    SHELL_COMMAND=pwsh
else ifneq (, $(shell which powershell))
    SHELL_COMMAND=powershell
endif

initialize: $(INITIALIZERS) .env

.env:
    cp .env.dev.dist .env

initialize-windows:
    @echo "Initializing Windows..."
    $(SHELL_COMMAND) -File .devcontainer/setup-ssh-agent.ps1

initialize-linux:
    @echo "Initializing Linux..."
```

call from .devcontainer/devcontainer.json with:

```json
"initializeCommand": "make initialize --ignore-errors -f .devcontainer/Makefile",
```

and here is the script that's referenced if anyone is interested:
setup-ssh-agent.ps1

```
if ($(Get-Service -Name ssh-agent).Status -ne 'Running')
{   
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/57035712/1973777
    if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)) {
        Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"cd '$pwd'; & '$PSCommandPath';`"";
        exit;
    }

    Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
    Start-Service ssh-agent
    Write-Output "SSH-Agent Started..."
}
else
{
    Write-Output "SSH-Agent Already Running..."
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark it as best answer now as I don't think there's anything better, but looking for something that requires less preparation from users that would run just based on VSCode and system tools.